# Database connection in windows 7 phone application using visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, database-connection

Am newbie to Windows 7 mobile Application development.In my app i have to use Database connection .i found the sqlce tool in visual-studio-2010 and i have created Db too. But i can't make DB connection ,Because i can't found Namespace to use Sqlce. please help me to find solution,if my approach is wrong please guide me to get solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have not provided any mechanisms for accessing a database in the first release of Windows Phone 7, so right now you can access a SQL CE database.

That said there are other options (web services and 3rd party databases using Isolated Storage on the phone).

For more information, see this question: [How to use the class SqlCeConnection in the Window Phone 7 application ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343533/how-to-use-the-class-sqlceconnection-in-the-window-phone-7-application)

Comment: I saw that given link, it shows 3 examples like 3rd party databases available, whether it support sqlite db?

Comment: There is *some* SQLite support for WP7: http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/. You'll need to understand the limitations of Isolated Storage and don't expect LINQ support (at least not yet). Haven't tried it myself, but looks like some folks are using it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few database libraries available now for WP7 - one of the best ones (IMO) seems to be the Sterling database - see http://sterling.codeplex.com/

Comment: there are sqlite libraries available - http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/ - but if I were starting with a "clean slate" then I'd personally pick Sterling right now.

Comment: if i add the any dll(like sqllite3.dll,sqlliteclient.dll) i am getting below msg pls guide me      : Reference cannot be added to l because it was not built using the Windows Phone runtime. Windows Phone projects will work only with Windows Phone assemblies.

Comment: Make sure you're either using the WP7 specific DLL - or a Silverlight DLL (SL3 preferred, but SL4 DLLs can also work)